# SVG Error: Root Element Namespace does not Match that Requested

Tags: svg, batik

I am currently running into the following error when trying to load an SVG file into my java application using Apache's Batik library:

```
java.io.IOException: Root element namespace does not match that requested:
Requested: http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
Found: null
```

I know that this question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038459/svg-batik-root-element-namespace-does-not-match-that-requested), but the OP's solution was to remove an invalid element.

Does anyone know anything else on this error? Below is my svg file that is causing the exception:

```
<div id="MapMarker">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="41 -24 118 178" width="118" height="178" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny">
        <path fill="rgb(255, 128, 128)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" d="M 45 150 L 45 70 L 100 20 L 155 70 L 155 150" />
        <path fill="rgb(255, 255, 128)" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" d="M 90 135 l 0 -10 l 5 -5 l 0 -55 l 5 -5 l 5 5 l 0 55 l 5 5 l 0 10 l -10 -10 Z" />
        <text font-family="Arial" font-size="30" font-weight="bold" fill="black" stroke="none" stroke-width="4" text-anchor="middle" x="68" y="110">S</text>
        <text font-family="Arial" font-size="30" font-weight="bold" fill="black" stroke="none" stroke-width="4" text-anchor="middle" x="132" y="110">A</text>
        <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" transform="translate(0)">
            <path d="M 100 10 L 100 -15" />
            <path d="M 120 10 L 120 -15" />
            <path d="M 80 10 L 80 -15" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: The `<div>` is not a valid SVG element at that position. Remove it and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @Sirko. That was the issue.